# Story Identification: movie about a professor getting an unknown parasite and infecting his students for a study

Tags: story-identification, movie

The title says most of it, really. I saw parts of it on TV when I was a kid, in my old house (>15 years ago).

- The main character was a professor getting infected with some kind of alien parasite
- He was played by someone that to a young kid looked A LOT like Chuck Norris
- This parasite would give him some strange abilities such as ultra fast reading, but would appear on his skin on boils and would itch (I specifically remember this scene where he was reading and scratching the back of his hand, then he would look at it and see this giant boil)
- He decided to select a group of "volunteers" from his students (probably college/grad school) to infect them with it and see the results
- He asked them to be tattoo-free and to strip naked so he could take note of marks on their bodies before infecting them

Aaaand nudity is when my parents drew the line and sent me to bed :)

**What is this movie called?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a movie, but rather an episode of "The Outer Limits", called "Double Helix", described as follows:

> After developing the liquid that acts on the intron (genetic material in DNA that acts as spacers and does not code for protein) he tests it on fish, and found that the liquid transforms the fish to amphibia. Then he tests it on himself, and begins experiencing strange symptoms, including a sort of map that grows on his back and a pattern that grows on his hand.
>
> Shortly after he begins looking for students that are suitable candidates. They have to have a high IQ, never had surgery, and are free from imperfections such as tattoos or glasses. They also have to be in a certain age, weight, and height range.

Comment: Absolutely flawless answer, thank you very much!
Also, Ryan Reynolds is in this, and definitely not Chuck Norris. O well.

Comment: Ron Rifkin though, I actually can see what you saw there as Chuck Norris.  He does kind of vaguely resemble him facially, if he was older, more bookish, and less Chuck Norrissy.